# move_uploaded_file was not working on server side

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I write my php and html code, it was not working while hosting on the server.

```
<form class="form-horizontal style-form"   enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"   action="insert.php">

                  <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"> Name *</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-4">
                              <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" id="sname" name="sname"/>
                          </div>

                            <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Upload *</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-4">
                              <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Filename" required="" name="file"/>
                          </div> 
                      </div>  
                          <div class="col-sm-8" > </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-2">
                         <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-theme" name="softsubmit" value="Submit">

                          </div>
                         </form>
```

and my insert.php file is:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['softsubmit'])) 
{ 
$sname=$_POST['sname'];
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
$file_size =$_FILES['file']['size']; 
$file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
$file_type=$_FILES['file']['type']; 
$tmp="uploads/".$file_name; 
$ok = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$tmp);
if($ok == true)
 echo 'success';
  else
   echo 'error';
  }
```

ERROR:

> "move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpkEr7JN' to
>   '/home/novasoftco/public_html/adminuploads/TNEB Online Payment.zip'"

Comment: There's just html code.

Comment: post the insert.php file code

Comment: <?php
 if(isset($_POST['softsubmit']))
  {
   
  $sname=$_POST['sname'];
 
   $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
      
    $tmp="uploads/".$file_name;
    
    $ok = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$tmp);

Comment: Edit question and paste code there. Provide symptoms of "not working" aswell.

Comment: yeah sure . i can do

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any errors, either in the browser or in the server's error log?

Comment: while i am going to add a file , its shows me error to upload,

Comment: file was not move to directory

Comment: @D.lakshmanan you are using relative path for destination check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given the **relative path** for destination

You need to specify the **absolute path** to the function. `move_uploaded_file()`

The following line will help you

```
$tmp = dirname(__FILE__) . "/uploads/" . $file_name;
$ok  = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $tmp);
```

`move_uploaded_file` never creates the folder itself, so you need to create the folder **uploads** manually.

Also set the uploads folder permission to 755

Comment: i already  create a folder bro ..

Comment: try above code bro. it should work.

Comment: i add your coding to my file, but i dont know its shows same

Comment: please dirname(__FILE__).

Comment: where is your upload folder? same folder script running?

Comment: No `dirname(__FILE__)` get the current working folder

Comment: Code is perfectly fine. its working for me in my machine.

Comment: if any permission to access the root folder ???

Comment: `var_dump(error_get_last());` add this line at last and run the code check what is the err you get

Comment: i notify my error bro..  please

Comment: see i updated the answer, there should be forward slash before the upload you are missing that

Comment: @D.lakshmanan Worked ??

Comment: your mail id please .,